# Java: I cannot execute a compiled Java code

Tags: java

```
C:\Users\YusufGalip\Desktop\JavaDeneme>java deneme
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: deneme has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I got this error when i tried to run a compiled program.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably compiled with a more recent version of java than the one you are attempting to use running the program. Do you have multiple versions of Java installed?

Try `java -version` and `javac -version` and compare the versions. If you use and IDE/editor where Java is configured in the settings, see that it points to the expected directory.

Comment: javac version is 11.0.1 and java version is 1.8.0_191 but i couldn't find version 11 for java

Answer (score 1):

You've compiled your class with Java 11 (55) while you're still trying to execute/run them using Java-8(52).

Either compile the code using Java-8 or execute with Java-11.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says that the compiler version was higher than the JVM version with which you are trying to run. That is why you are getting the error on running.

> Java 8 uses major version 52
>
> Java 11 uses major version 55

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout

Comment: I use JDK11 and I searched for JRE11 too but it seems jre 8 is the latest version.

Comment: Oracle has stopped releasing separate JREs for JDK 11, you would find the `java` command to run your program in the JDK installation itself. For me it was in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe`

Answer (score 0):

=================

## @DO THE FOLLOWING

change your path to point to a more recent version or if you are aware of the version using which the program was compiled, install the version and then execute the same command to run

1) run java -version now 
2) Note down the version
3) complete the above @DO ****
4) execute 1) again
5) you should see a different or the latest version
6) run your program :) and you should be able to .... post your results

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved with your help.
There were 2 Java in my computer one of them is "Java SDK Tools 11" and the second one is "Java Runtime 8" I uninstalled the "Java Runtime 8" and it worked.Thank you for your help.